# How to sum file sizes using bc and stat

Tags: command-line

I want to perform bc command on this output in order to get the sum of them.

```
Command:

stat --format=%s /etc/*.conf | paste -sd "+" -

Output:-

2981+6790+2969+604+346+2584+4781+9+144+34+191+599+973+497+552+3173+23+1963+2683+1260
```

Comment: ... pipe the result to `bc`?

Comment: It gives me an error:- " bash: bc: command not found
paste: write error: Broken pipe "

Comment: Maybe `bc` is not installed, so you must install it. Try `sudo apt install bc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With `bc`

Install `bc`,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bc
```

Now you can pipe to `bc` according to @steeldriver's comment,

```
$ stat --format=%s /etc/*.conf | paste -sd "+" - | bc
112126
```

### Without `bc`

You can also let the bash shell calculate the sum `$(( ... ))` of the output of the command,

```
$ echo $(( $(stat --format=%s /etc/*.conf | paste -sd "+" - ) ))
112126
```

Please notice that I show the result in *my* Lubuntu system, your result will probably be different.